# simple_form creates parentheses in name of form field

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I have a birthday in my User model and I used the example simple_form uses for a birthday:

```
<%= f.label "When is your birthday?" %>
<%= f.input :birthday, as: :date, start_year: Date.today.year - 60,
                      end_year: Date.today.year, order: [:month, :day, :year], label: false %>
```

This creates the names birthday(1i), birthday(2i), birthday(3i) which then causes this mass-assignment error:

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: birthday(2i), birthday(3i), birthday(1i)
```

Now how do I add symbolic names with parentheses to the attr_accessible method?

Comment: do you have `:birthday` in your attr_accessible?

Comment: Wow, that did it.  But now I have a new problem.  Any month I select I cannot select higher than the 12th day of each month.  It says "Please enter a valid date".

Comment: could you show your `params` when you get these validation errors?

Comment: @mikeglaz "Please enter a valid date" is perhaps Ruby Date parsing error as you are selecting month higher then `12` that perhaps not valid date format